# How to Rename a Visual Studio Project?

Tags: visual-studio

I have a project, say 'BlankConsoleApp', and I want to rename it. How can I do it?

Comment: @ superuser closer: ? huh ? How is a VS question relevant to SU?

Comment: @code poet - my guess is because he's not asking anything programming related, its more of a 'how do i do X task in Y program?' question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click the project in Solution Explorer and select 'Rename'